# Optional<T> implementation - disable Optional(U&&) constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on an `Optional<T>` class because I'm using c++11 and the compiler does not provide an implementation. I have problem with the rvalue reference constructor. The following constructors seems to work fine

```
Optional();

Optional(const ThisType& other);
Optional(ThisType&& other);

template <typename U>
Optional(const Optional<U>& other);
template <typename U>
Optional(Optional<U>&& other);

template <typename... Args>
explicit Optional(Unused, Args&&... args);
template <typename U, typename... Args>
explicit Optional(Unused, InitializerList<U> initList, Args&&... args);

template <typename U>
Optional(const U& value);
```

Where `ValueType` is a `typedef T` and `ThisType` is a `typedef Optional<T>`. However when I'm trying to implement an `rvalue reference of U` constructor:

```
template <typename U>
Optional(U&& value);
```

then the following test case is not working:

```
// Optional<T>(const Optional<T>&)
Opt o(Unused{});
Opt o2 = o;
```

The compiler tries to resolve this using the `Optional<T>(U&&)` and it of course cannot convert `Optional<T>` to `T`, where `Optional<T>` is `Opt` and `T` is `Foo`

`error C2664: 'Foo::Foo(Foo &&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Opt' to 'const Foo &'`

If I change the test case from `Opt o(Unused{});` to `const Opt o(Unused{});` it works fine, but that's not a solution.

I've tried to use `enable_if` on the rvalue constructor with no luck. I thought that I should enable this when the type of `U` is not an `Optional<U>` but probably I'm wrong.

```
template <typename U, typename = typename EnableIf<!IsSame<DecayT<U>, Optional<U>>::Value>::Type>
Optional(U&& value);
```

**Edit**

The following code can be copy-pasted into a file. I'm using VS 2013 and I double-checked that this version calls the proper constructors. There are 4 lines with comments `<--- error here` - if you comment out the `Optional(U&&)` constructor, those lines are ok.

Here is the link: http://pastebin.com/RLkwF64y

**Edit 2017-01-30**

Updated the pastebin link.

**Edit 2017-01-30 #2**

Decided to drop the `const U&` and `U&&` constructors. Most of the time the simple `const ValueType&` and `ValueType&&` will be sufficient.

Comment: Please provide MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Note that an "optional" type may be tricky to implement in C++11 if you want to support, say, classes with `const` members.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yea, that's true, but I would use it by myself - most of the time with simple types. However, this problem seems to be more "generic". I guess, the enable_if is the key but I'm failing to apply it properly.

Comment: I had to add the implementation to the "MCVE" because without that the code compiles.